# `<input type="date" />` Update State in React only when a user hits Enter or picks a date through the date picker

Tags: html, reactjs, datetime, jsx

I have tried the following so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function DateInput() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState('');

  const handleDateChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedDate(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      setSelectedDate(event.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="date"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
      <p>Selected Date: {selectedDate}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DateInput;
```

I only want to update state when I hit enter or when I choose a date through the GUI. Is there any good way to do this?

The problem with the method above is onChange gets called on every keystroke.

Comment: Remove the onKeyDown binding.

Comment: If I remove the onkeydown binding, hitting enter wouldn't update state. I only want to update state when I hit enter or when I choose a date through the datepicker/calendar.

Comment: What about listening to onInput? Alternatively, check what key is pressed onKeyDown before calling the handler.